# LenovoY-50 not responding after hibernation?

Tags: 14.04, lenovo

I have a Lenovo y-50 with Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 LTS, that does not work after I close and open up the lid. I always have to restart the computer to resume working. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Check [this tutorial](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/enable-hibernate-ubuntu-14-04/), maybe you have worng configurations, if not, I suggest deactivate hibernation on your computer, and revert to suspend mode.